Literature on Fréchet quasi-coherent sheaves
I've heard/read it said many times that "the good notion of quasi-coherent sheaf for complex manifolds is that of a Fréchet quasi-coherent sheaf", and the standard citation to which I've been pointed is Eschmeier and Putinar's book Spectral Decompositions And Analytic Sheaves.
There, in Section 4.6, we find the following quote (emphasis mine):

The literature concerning quasi-coherent analytic Fréchet sheaves is not so plentiful, and is always related to concrete applications. We mention only the article of Ramis and Ruget (1974), where this class of sheaves was introduced, and a monograph on deformation theory by Bingener and Kosarew (1987) where this class of sheaves is used for other applications.

The article of Ramis and Ruget is "Résidus et dualité", and the one of Bingener and Kosarew is Lokale Modulräume in der analytischen Geometrie, Volume 2 (ISBN: 3528063017).
The latter is a ~700 page book in German, and the combination of the length and language make it a... difficult reference for me to get much out of. This is particularly annoying because I would love to know about the "other applications" for which they use quasi-coherent analytic sheaves.
Question.
Are there any "modern" references for the theory of quasi-coherent analytic sheaves?
I have also been told a few times that the theory of condensed/liquid things can provide a different approach, avoiding the need for quasi-coherent analytic sheaves, but I've never found a reference that explains why this is so (in particular, this would count as a "modern" reference for quasi-coherent analytic sheaves).

In addition to the Clausen-Scholze literature see also https://arxiv.org/abs/2405.07936 which develops a general approach to analytic geometry (including quasicoherent sheaf categories) based on ind-Banach spaces

oh this is a very helpful reference, thank you!

I am not accessible to the two books that you mentioned. I glance at Ramis–Ruget, and if I understand correctly, their dual nuclear Fréchet quasicoherent modules form a full subcategory of that of nuclear quasicoherent sheaves à la Clausen–Scholze, more-or-less directly by definition.
Over a point, this is explained in Theorem 8.15 of [Clausen–Scholze, Condensed Mathematics and Complex Geometry], namely, a basic nuclear $p$-liquid $\mathbb C$-module (spectrum) is quasi-isomorphic to a complex of dual nuclear Fréchet spaces, and in particular, dual nuclear Fréchet spaces form a full subcategory of basic nuclear objects. This inclusion has a canonical symmetric monoidal structure, since dual nuclear Fréchet spaces are sequential colimits of $\mathcal M_{<p}(\mathbb N)$, thus flat (c.f. loc. cit. Proof of Lemma 8.7).
In general, first, by loc. cit. Corollary 8.20, on a compact Stein, an object is nuclear if and only if it is nuclear after (derived) pushforward to a point. Next, in Ramis–Ruget, their definition of quasicoherence is that, for every inclusion $L\subseteq K$, the canonical map
$$\mathcal M(K)\otimes_{\mathcal O(K)}^L\mathcal O(L)\xrightarrow\simeq\mathcal M(L),$$
is an isomorphism (they demand this on $H_0$, but also the vanishing of higher Tor groups), and this corresponds to the definition in Clausen–Scholze.

For the condensed approach to quasi-coherent sheaves on complex manifolds, see Clausen’s notes here, where the Talk 2 and 3 are exactly what you want.
Let $M$ be a complex manifold, Clausen’s motivation here is to make sense of the notion of “analytic $K$-theory” $K^{\mathrm{an}}(M)$ of $M$, and make it match the Deligne cohomology in a form similar to the Hodge conjecture. And to do so, one needs a suitable analogy for $\operatorname{Vect}(M)$ or $\operatorname{Perf}(M)$ in algebraic $K$-theory and the Hodge conjecture. This ultimately leads to the definition of $\operatorname{Nuc}(M)\subset D_{\mathrm{qc}}(M)$.
You can also find an expanded version of Talk 1 and some more background in these notes by Clausen–Scholze.

this is a great answer, and I'm sorry that I can only mark one as accepted!
